# Android Studio (not installed) in flutter in linux mint

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I installed flutter and android studio following the steps in the flutter  official page. I did it a month ago and then I used  `flutter doctor` and I did not get any problems back then.
Now I tried again but I keep getting those errors

[image]

I have Android Studio installed (version 4.1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not installing android studio into the recommended location. Then you need to link it back for Flutter doctor to find it.

I install android studio to my home dir "/home/{$USER}/android-studio"

The quick and dirty way is cd into your "/opt"  folder then symlink it

```sh
$ cd /opt
$ sudo ln -s /home/me/android-studio android-studio
```

Then run `flutter doctor` (or with a `-v` to see more detail) you should able to see it finds it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run the command as said `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.
It will show you the licenses and you just have to type Y in the command line to accept them.
Secondly,it seems can't find Android Studio. If you have that, I suggest you to uninstall and re-install it clearly. Of course you should also install the Flutter plugin in Android Studio.
When everything is done just use `flutter doctor`. The last warning "Connected device" is going to be visible until you don't use an emulator or connect via USB debugging your phone.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Flutter not being able to find Android Studio: I had the same issue since upgrading to Android Studio 4.1 a couple of days ago. Since I use VS Code it didn't bother me too much. However yesterday I received an update notification from Flutter and after the update the problem went away.